# The difference between medals and trophies

Tags: trivia, awards

Olympic champions win medals,
while FIFA champions win trophies.

Why do the winners receive a different object as an award?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This general trend holds across most sports, but does not generally rely on the nature of the sport itself.

The reasoning behind any particular organisation's award of either a trophy or medal (or other object) can vary, but is generally based on tradition - copied from similar events/sports/organisations or from the originators of the cup-shaped trophy most commonly used, the ancient Greek Olympic games (which awarded the winner an [*amphora*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphora) of sacred oil).

Teams as a whole will usually receive a significant object as a trophy, while individuals receive a smaller token like a medal.

However, this is not a universal rule.

- Individual players in the FIFA World Cups are given medals, in addition to the team being awarded the trophy
- The individual winner of many competitions is awarded a trophy (and usually a separate smaller replica, which they keep after the main trophy is given up)
- The winners of combat sport events or titles is often awarded a belt